# How to select rows according to time interval in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, time

I have a DB that have timestamp like this :

```
2018-10-25 13:00:00 
2018-10-25 15:00:10 
2018-10-25 16:10:00 
2018-10-25 17:00:00
```

Now I want to select only date from the last hour 
I have tried to run this -

```
SELECT * FROM sample.writing where (date(Date) = interval 1 hour )
```

What is wrong ?
Date is `DateTime` type.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firstly, `Date` is a [Keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-D). You should really avoid using it as a table/column name.
- To get a time 1 hour before the current time, you can add an `INTERVAL -1 HOUR` to current time (`NOW()`), using [`Date_add()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function.
- We can use [`BETWEEN low-value AND high-value`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) comparison operator, to get the values from the prescribed range.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sample.writing 
where Date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR) AND NOW()
```

Comment: working , Thanks!  ---- also how can I tell him to start look from specific time ? to start look from 2018-10-25 15:35:00?

Comment: @David12123 just change the arguments on both sides of the `between .. and ..`

Comment: Working - Thanks again !

Comment: @Strawberry updated the answer; thanks for pointing out. I believe that we should still use backticks (MySQL only) if it is a Reserved keyword instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table only stores past events...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sample.writing 
 where date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```