# How to make query that selects based on 1 day interval?

Tags: sql, select, count, subquery

How can I get all IDs that have more than 10 entries on one day?

Here is the **sample data:**

```
ID  |    Time
__________________________
4   |  2019-02-14 17:22:43
__________________________
2   |  2019-04-27 07:51:09
__________________________
83  |  2018-01-07 08:38:37
__________________________
```

I am having a hard time using `count` and going through and finding all of the ones on the same day. The Hour:Min:Sec is what is causing problems for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select rows according to time interval in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990201/how-to-select-rows-according-to-time-interval-in-mysql)

Comment: @Xxmarijnw Yes that question is somewhat similar but how would I change it so it is not one interval, but all 1 day intervals? In the linked question they use `now` but I cannot use that. See updated data

Comment: you can compare with ` WHERE Time IS '2019-02-14%'` where % smybolises a wildcard

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please add the relevant tags.

Comment: @stickybit this is a theoretical question someone asked me

Comment: @Jac: Then the theoretical answer is: `GROUP BY` the ID and the day, that you extract from the date/time by any means necessary to do so (and which depend heavily on the actual DBMS) and use `HAVING count(*) > 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **MySql** it would be:

```
select distinct id from tablename
group by id, date(time)
having count(*) > 10
```

The `date()` function rejects the time part of the column, so the grouping is done only by the date part.
For **SqlServer** you would use:

```
convert(date, time)
```